# How to add commas to numbers in gridview asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am running VS 2013. I am trying to add commas to numbers (ex 2000 should be 2,000). I have used `DataFormatString="{0:N0}"` but it's not working.

Is there another solution?

Here is my markup:

```
<asp:Label ID="gvCaptionN" CssClass="gvCaption" runat="server">NEW FIRST TIME FRESHMAN</asp:Label><br />
<asp:GridView Width="800px" ID="MyGridView1" DataSourceID="DataSource1" 
     AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="Server"
     BorderColor="#555555" HorizontalAlign="Center"
     Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="12px" AllowSorting="True" EmptyDataRowStyle-Font-Bold="true" EmptyDataRowStyle-ForeColor="#CC0000">
     <EmptyDataTemplate>*** No data available ***</EmptyDataTemplate>
     <%-- Do not put the header styles in separate headerstyle tag, 
          because when exporting to excel, that will change the color of 
          first row even outside the table in Excel --%>
     <Columns>
         <asp:BoundField HeaderText="NEW FIRST-TIME FRESHMEN" 
              HtmlEncode="false" DataField="NEW FIRST-TIME FRESHMEN" 
              ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
              HeaderStyle-BackColor="#CC0000" HeaderStyle-BorderColor="#555555" 
              ItemStyle-BorderColor="#555555" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="#FFFFFF" 
              HeaderStyle-Width="260px" ReadOnly="true" 
              DataFormatString="{0:N0}" />
         <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Last_Term" DataField="Last_Term" 
              ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" 
              HeaderStyle-BackColor="#CC0000" HeaderStyle-BorderColor="#555555" 
              ItemStyle-BorderColor="#555555" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="#FFFFFF" 
              HeaderStyle-Width="125px" ReadOnly="true" 
              DataFormatString="{0:N0}"  /> 
      </Columns>
</asp:GridView>                                             
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DataSource1" runat="server" 
     onselecting="DataSource1_Selecting"  DataSourceMode="DataSet"  
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnStringExtracts_IRDW %>"
     EnableCaching="true" CacheDuration="10800"
     SelectCommand="dbo.SP_FB_UNCERT_ENR_IRDW" 
     SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
     <SelectParameters>
         <asp:Parameter Name="reportType" Type="String" DefaultValue="UNCERTNEWFRESH" />
         <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ENRDropDownList" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="Term"
              Type="int32" DefaultValue="20172" />
     </SelectParameters>
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: What type is ``Last_Term``? And are you sure that the ``DataField`` for the first column in correct ``NEW FIRST-TIME FRESHMEN`` ?

Comment: What is the datatype of `NEW FIRST-TIME FRESHMEN`. If it is a string then this won't work.

Comment: @VDWWD since it contains spaces it should be invalid, is my guess.

Comment: Last_Term is of type int

Comment: i am mostly interested in just Last_Term and not NEW FIRST-TIME FRESHMEN.

Comment: Little google search gave, it seems you need to specify ``HtmlEncode="false"`` (dont ask me why)

Comment: @RandRandom, a column can contain spaces: `SELECT 25 AS [NEW FIRST-TIME FRESHMEN]`. It's not recommended though.

Comment: adding HtmlEncode="false" did not work. Any other solutions guys? Much appreciated.

Comment: You could always switch to a `TemplateField`, convert to integer and then format the number. `<ItemTemplate><%# string.Format("{0:N0}", Convert.ToInt32(Eval("NEW FIRST-TIME FRESHMEN"))) %></ItemTemplate>`. If you get an exeption there then the value if not an integer.

Comment: thats too much work, as i have 60 more fields like this.

Comment: Do it at back end ...